# Java Mockit : How to Mock a generic class method in JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, junit, jmockit

Hi I have the following classes

```
public class DataAccessLayer<T> {
  public T getData(Class<?> dataInfoType ,Integer id){
  //Some logic here
  } 
}

public class ServiceLayer{
    //this method has to be tested
     public Integer testingMethode{
         //The following line should be mocked
         UtilClass info =  new DataAccessLayer<UtilClass>().getData(UtilClass.class, 1); 
        retutn info.getSomeFieldWithIntegerValue();
     }
 }
```

I want to write test cases for testingMethode for that I need to mock the `getData()` method in `DataAccessLayer<T>`

Is it possible with `jmockit` to mock a Template(Generic ) class?

Comment: The typical way to mock a generic class in mockito is to define a non-generic subclass (e.g. `class UtilClassDataAccessLayer extends DataAccessLayer<UtilClass>`) and then create a mock of that class. Can you do something similar in jmockit?

Comment: I just tried it but not working for me. Can you post a sample snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic class can be mocked the same way a non-generic one:

```
@Test
public void example(@Mocked final DataAccessLayer<UtilClass> mock)
{
    final UtilClass data = new UtilClass(123);
    new Expectations() {{ mock.getData(UtilClass.class, 1); result = data; }};

    int result = new ServiceLayer().testingMethode();

    assertEquals(123, result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!Thats exactly what I was looking for .

Answer (score 2):

(I can only really answer for Mockito, as that is what I am most familiar with; but the same principle should be applicable in other mocking frameworks).

Firstly, you need to be able to inject a `DataAccessLayer<UtilClass>` into `ServiceLayer`, e.g.

```
class ServiceLayer {
  private final DataAccessLayer<UtilClass> dal;

  ServiceLayer(DataAccessLayer<UtilClass> dal) {
    this.dal = dal;
  }

  public Integer testingMethode() {
    UtilClass info = dal.getData(UtilClass.class, 1);
    return info.getSomeFieldWithIntegerValue();
  }
}
```

This breaks the static coupling to the `DataAccessLayer<UtilClass>` created by the use of the `new`.

Now, you can create a mocked instance of `DataAccessLayer<UtilClass>` by creating a non-generic subclass:

```
class UtilClassDataAccessLayer extends DataAccessLayer<UtilClass> {}
```

and then create a mock instance:

```
DataAccessLayer<UtilClass> mocked = mock(UtilClassDataAccessLayer.class);
```

Now, you can configure this mock as you need, and pass it into the `ServiceLayer`:

```
ServiceLayer serviceLayer = new ServiceLayer(mocked);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution!
That's a good working Idea but still is there any possible ways by which I can mock it without adding an additional variable field to the ServiceLayer?
Because as per our current design pattern of this application keeping this variable throughout the lifetime of the ServiceLayer object is not well appreciated.
If there are no other ways I would rather skip writing this test case

Answer (score 1):

In JMockit there's actually no need to create a holding variable in the `ServiceLayer` class, nor is there a need to make a parameterized subclass of your `DataLayer`. The following test works just fine:

```
package com.example.dsohl;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.equalTo;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import mockit.Deencapsulation;
import mockit.Expectations;
import mockit.Mocked;
import mockit.Tested;
import mockit.integration.junit4.JMockit;

@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class TestTest {

    public static class UtilClass {
        public Integer foo() {
            return 5;
        }
    }

    public static class DataLayer<T> {
        public T getItem(Class<T> clazz, int itemId) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class ServiceLayer {
        public Integer testMethod() {
            UtilClass util = new DataLayer<UtilClass>().getItem(UtilClass.class, 1);
            return util.foo();
        }
    }

// Test really begins here
    @Tested ServiceLayer svc;
    @Mocked DataLayer<UtilClass> data;
    @Mocked UtilClass util;

    @Test
    public void testDateSubtraction() throws Exception {
        new Expectations() {
            {
                new DataLayer<UtilClass>(); result = data;
                onInstance(data).getItem(UtilClass.class, 1); result = util;
                util.foo(); result = 37;
            }
        };

        Integer i = svc.testMethod();
        assertThat(i, equalTo(37));
    }

}
```

A few notes: First, my `DataLayer.getItem()` returns null so if the injection fails, we get a `NullPointerException`, nice and obvious. Obviously your code won't work like this; this is only to convince you.

Second, I use `onInstance()` so that we can be 100% certain that the result of the `DataLayer` constructor is what we are using in the next steps of the test. The default behaviour of `Expectations` on a `@Mocked` object is to record the expectation against any object of that class; this is how we are certain that it's *our* object that's being used. (Ordinarily I don't worry myself about this, but when using `new` I like to be certain.)

Finally, I'm omitting some other stuff I might do in cases like this, like use a `Verifications` block, etc. Just trying to be as straightforward as possible.

Enjoy!